# adapters call fails as there found to be unauthorized

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server, webseal

The hybrid android app made from mobilefirst cli 7.1 is not getting the authorization token from the mobilefirst server in our UAT environment which has webseal junction, so the subsequent adapters calls are failing as 401 unauthorized is returned for these calls, what makes this interesting is that ios app which is made from the same client side hybrid code works well with the same UAT environment with webseal.

one more interesting fact is that same android app works fine when pointed to SIT environment where there is no webseal .

So i am trying to understand what triggers the client ( WLHybridRequestSender)to send out the" /authorization/v1/token " call , and is there a chance that the webseal is filtering any response to a preceding call "token" call thats is breaking the client side code? if so where and what should i look for to resolve this issue?

Any advise or help is much appreciated !

Thanks

Comment: I think that you should examine the network using Wireshark, once with WebSEAL an another without it, to see the differences.

Comment: Have you attempted the above?

Answer (score 0):

This issue was already fixed, you can find more details about it, [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?crawler=1&uid=swg1PI59172).

You should update your *cordova-plugin-mfp 7.1.0* plugin using mobilefirst cli:

```
mfp cordova plugin update
```

This updates the `Cordova` assets for each plug-in that is installed in the app.

Please notice that you must execute the command in `Cordova` project folder.

You can read more about **mobilefirst cli** in this [tutorial](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/hello-world/integrating-mfpf-sdk-in-cordova-applications/).